# Cycle through nested generators once and repeat

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools

I want to yield through 2 different `itertools.count`. I have combined the two
generators using `itertools.chain.from_iterable`

This is the code I have written for it.

```py
return itertools.chain.from_iterable([itertools.count(start=2, step=2), itertools.count(start=7, step=7)])
```

The problem is that it is trying to finish the first counter (step 2) before proccding to yield over next counter (step 7)

Output from the above sample code:

```
2
4
6
8
10
...
```

But I want to cycle over alternatively.

Expected Output:

```
2  # 2*1
7  # 7*1
4  # 2*2
14 # 7*2
6  # 2*3
21 # 7*3
8  # 2*4
28 # 7*4
```

Here are the other ways I have tried so far:

```py
yield from [elem for elem in [next(count(start=2, step=2)), next(count(start=7, step=7))]]
```

The above cycles alternatively but the counter resets after each yield.

Output from the above code sample:

```py
2
7
2
7
2
7
```

I want this to be implemented entirely on `itertools` or list comprehension
since they are memory optimized, hence I expect the function to return a `generator object`. Also, it would be better if the solution is on a single line.

**EDIT:**

As suggested by [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) in the comment, I have implemented `roundrobin` iter technique and I am able to fetch the desired output.

```
from itertools import count, cycle

def pattern_generator():
    return cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in [
        count(start=2, step=2),
        count(start=7, step=7),
    ])

gen = pattern_generator()

print(next(gen)())
print(next(gen)())
print(next(gen)())
print(next(gen)())
```

I am satisfied with this output. But, is it possible to call `next` without calling the iter's next method? i.e., without using `()` in `next(gen)()`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you want the roundrobin recipe from https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. It is exactly what I am looking for. I have one more query and have reflected the same in my question. Anyways, I am partially satisfied now. Thanks again

Comment: Maybe you should use the actual recipe? You have to call `next(gen)` because `next(gen)` returns the `__next__`method, not the value it returns.

Comment: no, I am referring to the additional `()` after next call. But yeah, I am very satisfied with this implementation and have no issues. Thanks a lot

Comment: `next(gen)()`? Yes, exactly; ** because `next(gen)` returns a method**.

Comment: ooh, ok. I get it now. Thanks a lot buddy. The reason I am skeptical in installing `more-itertools`   package is, it's hard to convince my superiors

Comment: I'm not saying you should install anything, you can literally copy-paste the recipe from the itertools core library docs.

Comment: ok, didn't think about this earlier -_-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make generator in various ways

inline

```py
#for i in (i for t in zip('abc',range(3)) for i in t):
#EDIT: more readable solution
for i in itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip('abc',range(3))):
    print(i)
```

EDIT 2: explanation
`zip` connects n-th of each iterable (returns sequence of `tuple`s `('a', 0), ('b', 1) ...`)
so this roughly translates to `itertools.chain.from_iterable([('a', 0), ('b', 1), ...])`
calling `chain.from_iterable` is similar to calling `chain`
so now we have `chain(('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2))`
since `tuple`s are iterables, `chain` iterates through `('a', 0)`, and then `('b', 1)` and so on
`from_iterable` and `zip` are both needed because neither actually creates list `[('a', 0), ('b', 1), ...]` (which in your case would be infinite)

function 1

```py
def alternate(*iterables):
    for t in zip(*iterables):
        yield from t # or for i in t: yield i
```

function 2

```py
def alternate(*iterables):
    iterables = [iter(it) for it in iterables]
    while True:
        try:
            for it in iterables:
                yield next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

result

```py
for i in alternate('abc', range(3)):
    print(i)
a
0
b
1
c
2
```

function approaches also give larger flexibility

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, would have upvoted if I had the option to. But, I am trying to achieve this entirely using `generator` with a single command without the use of loops. Regardless, your answer is correct.

Comment: you could combine my first and `itertools.chain.from_iterable` and get `itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(itertools.count(start=2, step=2), itertools.count(start=7, step=7)))`

Comment: Yes, you are correct. This works. It would be really helpful is you can explain the working of the above example in your answer. Thanks in advance. You are awesome!